# Javascript - Using SQLite to specify the DB Location?

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, local

I was looking up on how to use sqllite to create and update a local db using javascript and I found this link:

> [SQLite database in Javascript locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244471/sqlite-database-in-javascript-locally)

Is there any way to specify the location for the db locally? I can't see any examples for this so perhaps not.. If not then where does it created the database?

Thanks a mill,
mcquaim

Comment: As far as I know you have no control over where the database is created. Different browsers already store them in different places. Are you having trouble finding the database for your application? Or is this just a general question?

Comment: Just a general question Frank! I am writing a little web page and I wanted to store the db in a certain directory but couldn't see how. It's it held in cache then or how does it work?

Comment: The workings of the database are internal to the browser. For example for Chrome the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8936878/209103

Comment: Thanks Frank! So, if that is determined by the browser then is there any way I could use a different method that I could specify the db location?

Comment: > As far as I know you have no control over where the database is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it doesn't seem to be possible to specify the DB location using this method.