# Connect sqlite to local db file with javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I cannot get javascript to connect to an existing sqlite database that I created and saved as a file with sqlite manager firefox extention.

This is my code but nothing is happening:

```
$(function() {
    var db;
    if(!window.openDatabase)
        alert('Sqlite not supported');
    else {
        db = window.openDatabase("testDb", "1.0", "DB", 1000000);        

        $("#resultList").html('');
        db.transaction(function(tx) {              
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM users', [], function(tx, result) {
                var dataset = result.rows;
                alert(result.rows.length - 1);
                for(var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
                    $("#resultList").append("<li>"+dataset.item(i)+"</li>");
                }
            });
        });
    }    
});
```

Not even the alert in `tx.executeSql` is alerting.

How do I do this then?

Comment: is this running as part of a HTML page? or as a .jscript file under a specific JS engine?

Comment: @Charl... This post may help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244471/sqlite-database-in-javascript-locally

Comment: It is running as a .js file